# DBNULL to String is not valid

Tags: datatable, crystal-reports

I have returning datatable which has a cell value of Nothing that passed from function `ex. row("incident_idcrimes")` is a **column** in a datable

`Controller.GetCrime(row("incident_idcrimes"))` is function that returns either has a value or nothing.

If it catch a return value of nothing using `try catch` then it will

```
Return Nothing
```

how do i create a formula that catch from passing function?

```
IF ISNULL({STAT.IDCRIMES}) = TRUE THEN "NONE" ELSE {STAT.IDCRIMES}
```

this formula give me an error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ISNULL({STAT.IDCRIMES})
```

this itself returns boolean (either true or false), what is the purpose of comparing this value again?

you can change as

```
IF ISNULL({STAT.IDCRIMES}) 
THEN "NONE" 
ELSE {STAT.IDCRIMES}
```

Edit*******************************

```
 IF {STAT.IDCRIMES}=cstr("")
    THEN "NONE" 
    ELSE {STAT.IDCRIMES}
```

Comment: still its getting the error. the source from database is NULL itself if is has no value at all

Comment: didn't get can you elaborate more?

Comment: the null value is actually has no data or is empty sir..still im getting error

Comment: what I have seen in the image is there is value as **(null)** in the column so I have suggested this approach. If it has no data have you tired like this `IF {STAT.IDCRIMES}=""`. Also let me know what datatype does **{STAT.IDCRIMES}** field holds

Comment: yes sir but still im getting error. the data is bind in Datatable which has as null value then fetch it data using Controller.GetCrime(row("incident_idcrimes")) if the return is nothing then my crystal report should also either an empty value else the return has value sir

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49955/discussion-between-siva-and-jane-smith)